# Kotlin idiomatic way to process collection as long as some condition holds

Tags: kotlin

I'd like to perform a transformation on objects in a collection as long as there are objects that satisfy a predicate.

After calling `transform(x)` the predicate no longer holds for `x` but may hold for some other `y` for which it didn't hold before. The algorithm is guaranteed to terminate, though.

How can this be improved?

```
while( col.any (p -> predicate(p)) ) {
    val member = col.find { p -> predicate(p) }!!
    transform(member)
}
```

**EDIT:**

Combining the answers by @jonrsharpe and @hotkey all of the following are more concise and efficient

```
do {
    val member = col.find { predicate(it) }?.also { transform(it) }
} while (member != null)


do {
} while (col.find { predicate(it) }?.also { transform(it) } != null)



while (col.find { predicate(it) }?.also { transform(it) } != null) {}
```

Comment: Does the transformation necessarily mean that the predicate no longer holds for that member?

Comment: Yes, after a call to `transform()` col has one less member that satisfies the predicate

Comment: Then maybe filter and map would be a simpler process?

Comment: So some member earlier in the list may now meet the predicate? In that case what you have is probably as clear as you'll get. You could use let to remove the temporary assignment: `col.firstOrNull { predicate(it) }?.let { transform(it) }`, perhaps.

Comment: Right, also `col.find { predicate(it) }?.let { transform(it) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) said in the comment, your code seems to search for the item that matches the `predicate` twice on each iteration, first time in `any` and then in `find` (they find the same item).

You can reduce that to only one search with `find`:

```
do {
    val member = col.find { predicate(it) }?.also { transform(it) }
} while (member != null)
```

Comment: Nice, two observations

1) this also works although its a bit unusual: `do {} while (col.find { predicate(it) }?.also { transform(it) } != null)`

2) this also works: `do {} while (col.find { predicate(it) }?.let { transform(it) } != null)`


because my `transform()` returns `Unit`, `let` returns `Unit` as long predicate matches and then `null`

Comment: And so finally we have this: `while (col.find { predicate(it) }?.also { transform(it) } != null) {}`

Comment: or even shorter `while(col.find(::predicate)?.also(::transform) != null);`